# How pages and posts are shown at wordpress with a url?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have been learning about wordpress and so far I knew how the posts and pages in wordpress basically works. But I have been wandering how the wordpress finds a specific page or posts for specific url.

For example; If I have a page named `hello-world` then how wordpress shows it as `localhost/wordpress/hello-world`. This case is same in case of pages too. I want to know how it really works.

First I thought it can be done by `.htaccess` file by changing the url or by simply renaming or deleting some parts of url like `localhost/wordpress/?page_name=hello-world` to `localhost/wordpress/hello-world`. But I cannot find it really on wordpress .htaccess file.

Help me out in this problem.

Comment: The post urls and GUIDs are all found in the database. in the wp_posts table

Comment: The structure can be changed under the permalinks settings in your admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

means that URLs that are not matched to filenames in the document tree will invoke index.php. index.php will eventually call WP::parse_request(). This function will parse the URL and generate a database query to find the post(s) or page(s) that correspond to the URL. This is quite a complex algorithm. parse_request() will try to match the URL against its own rewrite rules. If a match is found it will create a database query to fetch the matching post(s) or page(s). parse_request() is in the file .../wp-includes/class-wp.php - you can read it for yourself but it is not easy - I understood it once but I have forgotten the details.

ADDENDUM

I read the code and figured it out again. It isn't that hard. WordPress has a database of rewrite rules in the wp_options table with option_name "rewrite_rules".  A rewrite rule looks like this:

```
[(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

It maps regular expressions to a URL template. This particular rule is for pages (on my website, another website may have a different rule)

The URL http://localhost/tablepress-test/ matches this rule with match array:

```
$matches=Array
(
    [0] => tablepress-test
    [1] => tablepress-test
)
```

parse_request() rewrites the URL using the URL template to:

```
index.php?pagename=tablepress-test&page=
```

parse_request() then creates a database query with:

```
[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [page] => 
        [pagename] => tablepress-test
    )
```